# Should a junction table for a many-to-many relationship have a surrogate primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working with mySQL and Laravel. 
I have two tables: users and groups. Each has an id field and a name field.
I want users to be able to belong to many groups and vice versa; so I'm setting up a many to many relationship with a junction table: group_user.

My first thought is that it only needs two fields: user_id and group_id, both Foreign Keys.
But something tells me I might need/want an id for this table too. I've seen it both ways in code examples across the internet and I just want to know what I would be missing by not having it.

I just can't think of how I would actually make use of it; since the table is just to relate two other tables.

Comment: Short answer - yes, you want the PK there. If you don't specify one on your own, InnoDB (assuming you use InnoDB) will create a hidden 6 byte integer PK (which you won't have access to). There are many reasons why you want a PK, and they're not usually related to how things should be done but how they operate in real world.

Comment: Short answer - no. It MUST have a PK. It need not be surrogate. However, if you do use a surrogate then best practice suggests forming a natural (UNIQUE) key alongside. Personally, I think the surrogate's only really useful if you need to refer to that link in some other context. I can give a brief example if you like - but probably too long to comment here.

Comment: I want each user/group pair to be unique. Are composite keys inherently enforce unique as well? I think so, but not sure. Would it make sense to also make this a primary key? They will be queried by either the user_id or the group_id... So those should be indexed in some way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artificial primary key can be very useful sometimes in your code. For example when you would like to delete a record you can use the same pattern as in the case of other tables.
You have to pass only one id instead of the parts of the compound key.